# TVOS: Race condition at startup

Tags: race-condition, tvos, tvml, tvjs

Using the templates and TVML, I start my app with my own loading page, and then call a service to create the main page for the user.

If I initiate the call to the server inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I get the error `ITML <Error>: undefined is not an object - undefined - line:undefined:undefined`.

From this I assume my asynchronous call to the server is finishing before the javascript `App.onLaunch` function has completed, and I can only get it to work if I force a wait time before the server is called.

Here is the AppDelegate method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let appControllerContext = TVApplicationControllerContext()

        // our "base" is local
        if let jsBootUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("application", withExtension: "js") {
            appControllerContext.javaScriptApplicationURL = jsBootUrl
        }
        let jsBasePathURL = appControllerContext.javaScriptApplicationURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent
        baseUrl = jsBasePathURL?.absoluteString
        appControllerContext.launchOptions["BASEURL"] = jsBasePathURL?.absoluteString

        appController = TVApplicationController(context: appControllerContext, window: window, delegate: self)

        // initiate conversation with the server
        myPageCreator = PageCreator()
        myPageCreator?.delegate = self
        myPageCreator?.startDataCall(baseUrl!)

        return true
    }
```

Here is the (somewhat boilerplate) javascript function:

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    var javascriptFiles = [
        `${options.BASEURL}ResourceLoader.js`,
        `${options.BASEURL}Presenter.js`
    ];

    evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
        if (success) {

            resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader(options.BASEURL);
            var index = resourceLoader.loadResource(`${options.BASEURL}myLoadingPage.xml.js`,
                function(resource) {
                    var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
                    doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
                    navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
                });
        } else {
            /* handle error case here */
        }
    });
}
```

Now, if I change the call to the server in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and force it to wait, like this:

```
        ...
        // race condition hack:
        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "testing", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        return true
    }

    // initiate conversation with the server
    func testing() {
        myPageCreator = PageCreator()
        myPageCreator?.delegate = self
        myPageCreator?.startDataCall(baseUrl!)
    }
```

.. it will work. But I don't like that solution! What can I do to stop this race condition from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way for Javascript to communicate with Swift so that you know when **App.onLaunch** has finished running it's scripts.

Run this code in your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.  It will allow you to call **onLaunchDidFinishLoading()** in Javascript and handle the callback in Swift.

```
appController.evaluateInJavaScriptContext({(evaluation: JSContext) -> Void in
   let onLaunchDidFinishLoading : @convention(block) () -> Void = {
      () -> Void in
         //when onLaunchDidFinishLoading() is called in Javascript, the code written here will run.
         self.testing()
   }
   evaluation.setObject(unsafeBitCast(onLaunchDidFinishLoading, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "onLaunchDidFinishLoading")

   }, completion: {(Bool) -> Void in
})


func testing() {
    myPageCreator = PageCreator()
    myPageCreator?.delegate = self
    myPageCreator?.startDataCall(baseUrl!)
}
```

Inside **App.onLaunch** just add **onLaunchDidFinishLoading()** when the template is done being loaded.

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
var javascriptFiles = [
    `${options.BASEURL}ResourceLoader.js`,
    `${options.BASEURL}Presenter.js`
];

evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
    if (success) {

        resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader(options.BASEURL);
        var index = resourceLoader.loadResource(`${options.BASEURL}myLoadingPage.xml.js`,
            function(resource) {
                var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
                doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
                navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
                //ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE
                onLaunchDidFinishLoading();
            });
    } else {
        /* handle error case here */
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Yes. That works. It seems relatively complicated, on the native side, but it works!